# How exactly an empty "azurerm_subscription" data balock gets its Data Source Arguments?

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-azure

In the following example:

https://github.com/terraform-providers/terraform-provider-azurerm/blob/master/examples/app-service/function-azure-RBAC-role-assignment/main.tf

We have this code snippet:

[image]

In line 57, where the value of `data.azurerm_subscription.primary.id` is coming from? I am asking since The data block in the line 53 is empty.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you check the [data source documentation](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azurerm/latest/docs/data-sources/subscription) it doesn't require any input. The only optional argument is `subscription_id`:

> If this argument is omitted, the subscription ID of the current Azure Resource Manager provider is used.

Which depends on the way you [authenticate](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azurerm/latest/docs#authenticating-to-azure) with Azure.

If you're using Azure CLI, it should resolve to your Azure CLI default subscription (which you can find out with `az account show`).